# Rows are NOT Delete in Table in Aura component?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura

When, I clicked the delete button but the record not delete ?
Code:-

```
   <aura:component controller='AccToConActionInRow' implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
<!-- Handler to call function when page is loaded initially -->
<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.getContactsListController}" value="{!this}" />

<!-- List of contacts stored in attribute -->
<aura:attribute name="contactList" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="totalRecords" type="Integer" default="0"/>
<aura:attribute name="editData" type="boolean"/>
<aura:attribute name="deleteDataFlag" type="boolean"/>
Number of Contacts = <ui:outputText value="{!v.totalRecords}" />&nbsp;

<center><lightning:button 
                          variant="brand" 
                          label="Create Contact" 
                          iconName="utility:record_create" 
                          onclick="{!c.createContactController}"/></center>&nbsp;

<!--Table Start-->
<table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate" >Contact ID</span></th>
            <th scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate">First Name</span></th>
            <th scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate">Last Name</span></th>
            <th scope="col"><span class="slds-truncate">Action</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!!v.editData}">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.contactList}" var="objCon">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <ui:outputText value="{!objCon.Id}" /> 
                    </td>
                    <td> 
                        <ui:outputText value="{!objCon.FirstName}" /> 
                    </td>
                    <td> 
                        <ui:outputText value="{!objCon.LastName}" /> 
                    </td>                   
                    <td>
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!!v.editData}">
                            <lightning:button 
                                              label="Edit" 
                                              variant="brand"
                                              onclick="{!c.dataEditActionController}"/>
                        </aura:if>
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.deleteDataFlag}">
                            <lightning:button 
                                              variant="destructive" 
                                              label="Delete" 
                                              onclick="{!c.deleteContactsController}" />
                        </aura:if>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>
        </aura:if>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.editData}">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.contactList}" var="objCon">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <lightning:input value="{!objCon.FirstName}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <lightning:input value="{!objCon.LastName}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.editData}">
                            <lightning:button 
                                              variant="brand"
                                              label="Save"
                                              onclick="{!c.dataSaveActionController}"/>
                            <lightning:button 
                                              variant="destructive" 
                                              label="Cancel" 
                                              onclick="{!c.dataCancelActionController}"/>
                        </aura:if> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>
        </aura:if>
    </tbody>
</table>

<!--Table End-->
```

</aura:component>

Controller:-

```
({
   getContactsListController : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.deleteDataFlag",true);
    var action = component.get('c.serarchCurrentContacts');
    action.setParams({"accId" : component.get('v.recordId')});
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        if(response.getState() === 'SUCCESS'){
            console.log('success 
         '+JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
            
            var records = response.getReturnValue();
            records.forEach(function(record){
                record.linkName = '/'+record.Id;
            });
            component.set('v.contactList', records); 
            component.set('v.totalRecords' , records.length);
        }else{
            console.log('something went wrong...!!!!');
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
dataEditActionController : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.editData",true);
    component.set("v.deleteDataFlag",false);
},
dataSaveActionController : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.editData",false);
    component.set("v.deleteDataFlag",true);
    // Getting the contact list from lightning component
    var contactList = component.get("v.contactList"); 
    // Initializing the toast event to show toast
    var toastEvent = $A.get('e.force:showToast');
    // Defining the action to save contact List ( will call the 
        saveContactList apex controller )
    var saveAction = component.get("c.saveContactList");
    // setting the params to be passed to apex controller
    saveAction.setParams({ contactList : contactList });
    // callback action on getting the response from server
    saveAction.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        if(response.getState() === 'SUCCESS') {
            // Getting the response from server
            var dataMap = response.getReturnValue();
            // Checking if the status is success
            if(dataMap.status == 'success') {
                // Setting the success toast which is dismissable ( 
         vanish on timeout or on clicking X button )
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    'title': 'Success!',
                    'type': 'success',
                    'mode': 'dismissable',
                    'message': dataMap.message
                });
                // Fire success toast event ( Show toast )
                toastEvent.fire();   
                window.location.reload();
            }
            // Checking if the status is error 
            else if(dataMap.status == 'error') {
                // Setting the error toast which is dismissable ( 
            vanish on timeout or on clicking X button )
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    'title': 'Error!',
                    'type': 'error',
                    'mode': 'dismissable',
                    'message': dataMap.message
                });
                // Fire error toast event ( Show toast )
                toastEvent.fire();                
            }
        }
        else {
            // Show an alert if the state is incomplete or error
            alert('Error in getting data');
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(saveAction);
    
},
dataCancelActionController : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.editData",false);
    component.set("v.deleteDataFlag",true);
},
deleteContactsController : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('i am js delete method');
    component.set("v.deleteDataFlag",true);
    
    var action = component.get("c.deleteObject");
    var deleteid = event.getSource().getLocalId();
    action.setParams({"deleteId" : deleteid});
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if(state == 'SUCCESS') {
            var lst2 = [];
            var lst = component.get('v.contactList');
            lst.forEach(function (item, index) {
                if(item.Id != deleteid){
                    lst2.push(item);
                }
            });
            component.set('v.totalRecords',lst2.length);
            component.set('v.contactList',lst2);
        }else{
            console.log('Something went wrong....!!!!');
        } 
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
createContactController : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('i am JS controller Create Method');
    var createContact = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
    // Parameters like apiName and defaultValues are set
    createContact.setParams({
        "entityApiName": "Contact",
        "defaultFieldValues": {
            "AccountId": component.get("v.recordId")
        }
    });
    // Event fired and new contact dialog open
    createContact.fire();
   }
 })
```

Apex Class:-

```
  public class AccToConActionInRow {

  @AuraEnabled
  public static List<Contact> serarchCurrentContacts(String accId){
    try{
        Id accountId = Id.valueOf(accId);
        
        System.debug('#Calling = '+ accountId);
        
        return ([select Id, FirstName, LastName, LeadSource, Phone, 
      Email, Level__c from Contact where AccountId =: accountId 
      WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED]);
        
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
       }
   }

  @AuraEnabled
   public static Map<String,String> saveContactList(List<Contact> 
     contactList) {
      // Forming a  string map to return response
      Map<String,String> resultMap = new Map<String,String>();
      // Adding try catch for exception handling
      try {
        // Updating the Contact List
        update contactList;
        // Setting the success status and message in resultMap
        resultMap.put('status', 'success');
        resultMap.put('message', 'Contacts Updated Successfully');        
       }
      catch(Exception e) {
        // Setting the error status and message in resultMap
        resultMap.put('status', 'error');
        resultMap.put('message',e.getMessage());
      }
      // Returning the result string map
      return resultMap;
  }

@AuraEnabled
public static boolean deleteObject(string deleteId){
    Contact objCon = New Contact (id = deleteId);
    if(objCon != null){
        delete objCon;
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you have an uncaught exception in your js controller code. If you will wrap contents of the `deleteContactsController()` function in try-catch block as in the sample below and try to click your delete button, then you will see the error in the console log that your value of `deleteId` variable can't be accessed.

```
deleteContactsController: function (component, event, helper) {
    try {
      console.log("i am js delete method");

      var action = component.get("c.deleteObject");
      var deleteid = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
      console.log(deleteid);
      action.setParams({ deleteId: deleteid });
      action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state == "SUCCESS") {
          var lst2 = [];
          var lst = component.get("v.contactList");
          lst.forEach(function (item, index) {
            if (item.Id != deleteid) {
              lst2.push(item);
            }
          });
          component.set("v.contactList", lst2);
        } else {
          console.log("Something went wrong....!!!!");
        }
      });
      $A.enqueueAction(action);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

#### Update

1. add local id to your button

```
<lightning:button value="{!objCon.Id}"
                  variant="destructive" 
                  label="Delete" 
                  onclick="{!c.deleteContactsController}" />
```

2. access the id in the function

`var deleteid = event.getSource().get("v.value");`

proof it works:
[image: proof it works]

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at deleteContactsController (AccToConActionInRow.js:93:56)
    at K.Xc (aura_prod.js:569:177)
    at K.Ua (aura_prod.js:568:306)
    at handleClick (button.js:2:6)
    at K.Xc (aura_prod.js:569:177)
    at aura_prod.js:458:349
    at C.Ua (aura_prod.js:924:221)
    at Object.mj (aura_prod.js:458:333)
    at QJ.Sq (aura_prod.js:994:402)
    at cD.Bl (aura_prod.js:328:255)

Comment: Yes, because you don't have any `dataset.id` field on your button. When you click it, you can access the event object in your js function. but this event doesn't have `dataset` field. Thus, you have the exception, and your apex controller is not being exectued.

Comment: @CrazyMan can you share your `.cmp` file's code?

Comment: @CrazyMan updated my answer, it should work now.

Comment: I tried to add your updated code but it is still showing error means the error part is running that's why I have added the complete code of this component in the question. Please fix this code.

Comment: @CrazyMan I updated my answer above, proof in the end of the answer. By the way it was my bad for a little bit, the solution with `aura:id` wouldn't work anyway so I used a different approach.